# Prevent operators from being inserted into stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

Disclaimer: I'm terrible with C++;

I'm using a `wstringstream` to take objects from a vector and format their values into a string that can be stored in a 'file map' ( for IPC ).

```
std::wstringstream ss;
SDLWrap::frame obs = SDLWrap::getObs();
for (int i = 0; i < obs.pixels.size(); i++ )
{
    SDLWrap::pixel p = obs.pixels[i];
    ss << "{" << p.x << "," << p.y << "," << p.r << "," << p.g << "," << p.b << "}";
}
MemFile::writeMemData(TEXT("Local\\ReflexAIOut"), ss.str(), ss.str().length()*2);
```

The string is converted into an array of characters (`WCHAR`) and then put into memory. It seems the operators are also included in the string because the final result includes 3 NUL char's in place of the operators.

```
<mmap.mmap object at 0x00000185F9A8CF30>
b'{\x000\x00,\x000\x00,\x000\x00,\x000\x00,\x000\x00}\x00{\x000\x00,\x001\x00,\x000\x00,\x000\x00,\x000\x00}\x00{\x000\x00,\x002\x00,\x000\x00,\x000\x00,\x000\x00}...
```

Is there an easy way to concatenate these values without including the operator? I would like to avoid having to make another loop to remove the extra NUL characters.

Edit: Here's the writeMemData function

```
bool MemFile::writeMemData(std::wstring memName, std::wstring data, int size)
{
    HANDLE mapFile;
    LPCTSTR buff;

    mapFile = CreateFileMapping(
        INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
        NULL,
        PAGE_READWRITE,
        0,
        size,
        memName.c_str());

    if (mapFile == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    buff = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(mapFile,
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,
        0,
        0,
        size);

    if (buff == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    CopyMemory((PVOID)buff, data.c_str(), (_tcslen(data.c_str()) * sizeof(TCHAR)));

    UnmapViewOfFile(buff);
    openMem_.push_back(mapFile);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I added the writeMemData function.

Comment: The resulting data looks OK. Those `\x00` are high bytes of wide characters - you are using **w**stringstream, don't you?

Comment: `wchar`s are twice as big as `char`s, and they represent latin characters as 1 byte identical to the `char` representation, and 1 byte that is `0`. You are displaying your file's *bytes*, not it's *`wchar`s*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing to `std::wstringstream` that is stream of *wide* (16-bit, or 2-byte in your case*) characters. So for each 1-byte `char` put into that stream, 2-byte `wchar_t` comes out:

```
ss << "{" << p.x << "," << p.y << "," << p.r << "," << p.g << "," << p.b << "}";
//     |     |       |     |       |     |       |     |       |     |       |
//     {\x00 0\x00   ,\x00 0\x00   ,\x00 0\x00   ,\x00 0\x00   ,\x00 0\x00   }\x00
```

Those NUL bytes are high bytes of 2 byte pairs.

If you want your data encoded in 8-bit encoding, use `std::stringstream` instead of `std::wstringstream`.

* - standard does not define exact `wchar_t` size.